# CSS set height and width of SVG in li::before

Tags: html, css

I have the following list were I load some SVGs as list item. How can I set the height and width of the `::before` to for example 30px x 30px? I tried to set that directly with height and width already but that failed.  Could someone help me?

```
<div class="list-div">
<ul class="items-list">
          <li>Dies ist ein Eintrag A</li>
          <li>Dies ist ein Eintrag B</li>
          <li>Dies ist ein Eintrag C</li>
          <li>Dies ist ein Eintrag D</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS  :

```
.list-div li {
    opacity:0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  visibility: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
  .list-div li:nth-child(1){
background: url(some_image.svg);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(2){
background: url(some_image.svg);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;

}
.list-div li:nth-child(3){
background: url(some_image.svg);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;

}

.list-div li:nth-child(4){
background: url(some_image.svg);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the SVGs to be in front of the list item (like bullet points but with icons), or to only show instead of the text?

Comment: be in front of the list, centered vertically wit the text like the  actual CSS. Maybe background-size : 30px 30px could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```css
.list-div li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list-div li span {
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.list-div li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.list-div li:nth-child(1):before {
  background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png');
}
.list-div li:nth-child(2):before {
  background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/stackoverflow-512.png');
}
.list-div li:nth-child(3):before {
  background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/home-512.png');
}
.list-div li:nth-child(4):before {
  background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-back-512.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="list-div">
  <ul class="items-list">
    <li><span>Dies ist ein Eintrag A</span></li>
    <li><span>Dies ist ein Eintrag B</span></li>
    <li><span>Dies ist ein Eintrag C</span></li>
    <li><span>Dies ist ein Eintrag D</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This uses your idea of the `:before` selector with the list items to have your own icons show up instead. It is important to define `content` in this selector, even if empty, as it will not work. The size of the icon is set to be 30x30px and will sit in the middle of the text. I also added a `background-size: cover` tag so that the icons will be set to the same size as you define, meaning that if you decide to scale the icons later then they will work just as fine.

In order for the text to be centered with the icon, I wrapped each text item in a `<span>` tag which allows us to modify just the text without affecting the list item itself, or the `:before` selector. Here, we simply set the `line-height` and `height` of the text to be the same height as the image. If you want to resize the image, you will also need to change the value here.

I also modified your code a slight amount as you were reusing a lot of code that didn't need to be reused. For example, your `:nth-child(x)` selectors were using the exact same code with only one difference - the background image. To make this more efficient, I put all of the default code into one code block which will affect all of the list items in the same way as before. As the background image will be the only thing changing for the list, it's a good idea to have those as separate links.

Comment: Hey, thanks works great, but if there are multiple lines of text, the text starts below the icon,

Comment: The `line-height` approach will only work for one line of text unfortunately. If you're planning to have text on more than one line, do you still want the icon to be in the middle of it?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it with a background-height